# Column splitting in R

Tags: r, database

I am using a data frame, constructed from scraped data, which contains a character column. I am trying to split it into two columns, one which contains the elements before "|" and another which contains the elements after that symbol .

The column looks like this:

```
 [1] " 45  cubiertos | 1 . "
 [2] " 5000  cubiertos "    
 [3] " 45  cubiertos | 1 . "
 [4] " 60  cubiertos | 2 . "
 [5] " 57  cubiertos | 1 . "
 [6] " 35  cubiertos "     
 [7] " 70  cubiertos | 2 . "        
 [8] " 50  cubiertos | 2 . "        
 [9] " 45  cubiertos | 2 . "        
[10] " 146  cubiertos | 4 . "
```

I tried to solve this problem using this command (The first column indicates the how many meters an apartment has, and the second one the number of rooms.
)

```
reshape2::colsplit(alquileres_df$atributo,  "|" , names = c("metraje","dormitorios"))
```

However, i get the following output:

```
     metraje                   dormitorios
1         NA          45  cubiertos | 1 . 
2         NA              5000  cubiertos 
3         NA          45  cubiertos | 1 . 
4         NA          60  cubiertos | 2 . 
5         NA          57  cubiertos | 1 . 
6         NA                35  cubiertos 
7         NA          70  cubiertos | 2 . 
8         NA          50  cubiertos | 2 . 
9         NA          45  cubiertos | 2 . 
10        NA         146  cubiertos | 4 .
```

Also, note that sometimes the database does not have an "|" symbol, hence, the second column element may be empty.

Any idea of why is that happening? how can i solve it?

Thanks you!

Comment: Your data seems very messy, and incomplete.  Can you better format your question so that we can digest your data?

Comment: Done. Hope now you can understand better the data.

Comment: Replace `"|"` with `"\\|"` and you should be able to use `colsplit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
x <- c(" 45  cubiertos | 1 . ",
" 5000  cubiertos "    ,
" 45  cubiertos | 1 . ",
" 60  cubiertos | 2 . ",
" 57  cubiertos | 1 . ",
" 35  cubiertos "     ,
" 70  cubiertos | 2 . "        ,
" 50  cubiertos | 2 . "        ,
" 45  cubiertos | 2 . "        ,
 " 146  cubiertos | 4 . ")

library(stringr)
str_split(x,"\\|", simplify = TRUE)
```

It will give you two columns, where the first column will have everything before |, and the second column everything after. For the entries without |, the second column will have an entry like "".